# Git Issue with multiple computers

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I've set up a GitHub repository on my laptop today. I can submit code and all ... but now I want to have the same access with my PC. Do I need to configure the SSH keys etc all over again, with every box I want to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git with apache (http or https), Nice and easy way (in my opinion).

1. Server: Configuring Apache HTTPS In order to share your repository. (authorization with htaccess)
2. Client: Install tortoiseGIT, in order to checkout, commit, update or branch.

Answer (score 3):

You need SSH access on all computers that will commit code or sync with a private GitHub repository. You have two choices:

1. Use the same SSH key on all your client computers.
2. Use a different SSH key on each client computer.

Either way, your authorized SSH keys must be configured on GitHub to allow proper access. Obviously, option #1 is easier to manage, unless your Windows or Mac SSH client doesn't handle OpenSSH keys properly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes. You have to set up the security stuff, which is kind of unrelated to git itself. In the other PCs, you have to define a remote repository that contains the address of the repository on your computer. Then you can push to/pull from each other's repositories.